# MYSQL: Fetch same number of rows for different column values

Tags: mysql, sql

Ok so let's say I have this table

Table name: "example"

```
id | type  | value
-----------------
1  | color | blue
2  | plants| apple
3  | color | red
4  | color | yellow
5  | plants| grapes
6  | things| cellphone
```

How can I make a single query (or maybe with subqueries) to return 2 (or less if there are less data) rows for EACH `type`.

I can do this for individual queries:

```
select * from `example` where `type` = 'color' limit 2
```

I couldn't just use `where in` coz this will NOT return an EQUAL number of results.

Expected results: (2 or less for each type)

```
id | type  | value
-----------------
1  | color | blue
2  | plants| apple
3  | color | red
5  | plants| grapes
6  | things| cellphone
```

I'm using laravel eloquent for this btw, but a raw one is ok.

Comment: Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by type order by id) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum <= 2;
```

Comment: there's a syntax error near `(partition by type order by id) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum <= 2;`

Comment: @IamL the rest of the error message will give you the clue that your version of MySQL does not support window functions