# Laravel Mixing of GROUP columns (MIN(),MAX(),COUNT(),...) on a sub query with "ROW_NUMBER() OVER PARTITION"

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

I know there are tons of question that includes that error, but I haven't seen one that incldues a subquery with row_numbers.

Ok so I have this raw query which WORKS when I run directly on a database management application (I use sequel pro)

The ff info was actually taken from my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64120869/mysql-fetch-same-number-of-rows-for-different-column-values/64120905?noredirect=1#comment113387950_64120905):

I ended up having this query

```
select * from (select *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY type ORDER BY id) AS seqnum from `example`) as `t` where `seqnum` <= 50
```

This query works perfectly on sequel pro (database management application)

but when I do (wrap it on DB::statement in laravel):

```
DB::statement("select * from (select *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY type ORDER BY id) AS seqnum from `example`) as `t` where `seqnum` <= 50");
```

On Laravel I get:

```
Mixing of GROUP columns (MIN(),MAX(),COUNT(),...) with no GROUP columns is illegal if there is no GROUP BY clause
```

Any ideas why did it failed on laravel but was ok on a database management app?

Comment: Please post your laravel version, PHP version, MySQL version. Also, outside laravel in a regular PHP mysqli or PDO query can you successfully run query? Finally, are you absolutely sure your Sequel Pro and laravel connects to *same* database (not sandbox, dev, local, etc.)?

Comment: Some forum links suggest turning off `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` or specifically setting `'strict' => false` in your config/database.php file.

Comment: I have exactly the same issue with a query involving ROW_NUMBER(). Setting `'strict' => false` in the database makes the query work.  But I can't find a sensible explanation of why, and would really like to know the answer.

Answer (score -1):

Go to config/database.php and just change value of strict to false:

```
  'strict' => false, // <= be sure that this is set to false
```

https://floyk.com/en/post/how-to-fix-error-group-columns-is-illegal-if-there-is-no-group-by-clause